# Repeat the last line of the input using EOF(CTRL+D)

Tags: c, scanf, eof

When I put the values of my input and type ctrl + d the last line repeat and that is not suppost to happen. Anyone know what is happen?

```
  while(1) {
        if(getchar()==EOF)
            break;
        scanf(" %c %d", &s, &b)

  }
```

For example, image that I put (input)m 2 and the result of that is 5(output) if I click ctrl+d to finish the program the 5 is printed again and I don't want that.

Comment: Open the debugger and step through the code to see what really happens. Hint: `scanf` leaves characters in the input buffer.

Comment: The `scanf("%c %d",&s,&b);` might need a space before `%c` but has an unnecessary space before `%d`. Most `scanf` format specifiers, including `%d` filter out leading whitespace, but `%c` does not unless is preceded by a space. I suggest `scanf(" %c%d", &s, &b);` Notice the additional spaces after each comma – this is a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%c %d",&s,&b);` stops at the newline after your input, but it doesn't remove it from the input stream. So the next call to `getchar()` returns that newline character, and doesn't return `EOF`.

Then you call `scanf()` again, but don't check the result. There's nothing left for it to read, so it leaves the variables `s` and `b` unchanged, and you print that again.

Then you return to the top of the loop. Now `getchar()` returns `EOF`.

Change your loop condition to:

```
while (scanf(" %c %d", &s, &b))
```

and get rid of the `getchar()` check.

The space before `%c` will make it skip over any whitespace before the character.

Answer (score 1):

Never assume that `scanf` succeeded. Check its return value to make sure that it was able to read everything that you expect it to.

```
int n = scanf("%c %d",&s,&b);
if ( n != 2 )
{
   // deal with the error.
}
else
{
   // Use the data
}
```